# CLion Installation: Cmake compilers not found, GDB not found

Tags: clion

I'm switching from VS to CLion and they said I needed to install Cygwin and CMake. I then installed both of them. I tried use bundled, but CLion still gives me these errors `make: not found` `C Compiler: not found` `C++ Compiler: not found` `GDB: not found`.

I have installed CMake under the path `C:\Users\Gaga\Downloads\cmake-3.4.1` but I don't see a cmake.exe, the closest thing is cmake.cxx.

Without these I'm not able to compile anything, please help

[image]

Comment: `cmake.cxx` is a C++ source file. You probably downloaded CMake's source, which you'd need to compile. About the whole installation, I've had good results on Windows machines with [mingw-w64](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) and CLion's own CMake.

Comment: Not language-, but tool-specific.

Comment: @Quentin Ok I'll try to get mingw-w64 if none of this works out. But is there a way to compile CMake's source? Also should I `Use bundled CMake3.3.2`? When I ceck that I still get the same errors. Thanks

Comment: @Quentin I've downloaded the CMake installer and gotten the real thing and the exe. Thanks for the tip! I've gotten a new error `CMake:test run finished with errors CMake Error: The source directory "/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment0.tmp" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.`

Comment: I have the same error, any luck on this?

Comment: @sciencefyll Yes I have found a way and will post my full solution at home. Basically I worked around it.

Comment: https://medium.com/@RobertSimoes/installing-clion-on-windows-for-c-c-newbies-like-me-4a346aaf9557

I ended using this tutorial installing cygwin :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The workaround would be to use MinGW. If you download it from the website it should come with cmake, and take care of the errors.

http://mingw.org/

When extract it and go to the installer you should check something like gcc and then from the top left corner something like 'install packages'

Be sure not to accidentally download the source, which I did, which would lead you toward this error: [CLion: CMake Errors Source directory does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846948/clion-cmake-errors-source-directory-does-not-exist)

Edit: So over a year later, I've learned a little more about Cygwin and mingw beyond what the internet says. CLion needs a "Unix-like" environment. If you use CLion on MacOS or a Linux it's already Unix based. Anything that is "POSIX" compliant will work. CygWin is a terminal emulator for windows where Unix commands like `mkdir` work. MinGW is something similar but not posix. Comes with GCC tho. I'm still a noob.

Answer (score 7):

In the "Use specified" field I put `C:\cygwin64\bin\cmake.exe` your path may be different. Just ensure you have CMake, Make, gdb and gcc installed already in Cygwin (**using the Cygwin setup.exe** not via the CMake website) but I believe Clion checks if you have them installed after inputting the path. 
[image]

Comment: Clion should include these binaries in their src rather then making the lost users figuring it out by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
While installing cygwin, need to select the packages of cmake, gcc, gdb 
Got the answer from the below link.

[Select Packages while installing cygwin](https://medium.com/@RobertSimoes/installing-clion-on-windows-for-c-c-newbies-like-me-4a346aaf9557)

After the installation go to the configuration page and select the cygwin directory. CLion will identify the configuration and you are done...