# CLion: CMake Errors Source directory does not exist

Tags: c++, c, clion

I've been trying to get CLion to work. I've got the CMake installed, but it still gives me errors that I cannot find online. Can someone explain what the error means, if not how to fix it?

```
Cannot read C:\Users\Gaga\AppData\Local\Temp\cmake_check_environment0.tmp\_build0.tmp\CMakeCache.txt

Errors:
CMake Error: The source directory "/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment0.tmp" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

[image]