# Clion gdb not found, but working with netbeans

Tags: netbeans, gdb, clion

I've seen some other stakoverflow question like this one:

[CLion Installation: Cmake compilers not found, GDB not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846025/clion-installation-cmake-compilers-not-found-gdb-not-found)

But it's not quite the same problem.
My problem is that only my gdb.exe is not found by Clion. I can compile and run programs without problem, but when i need to debug the program tell me that only the  debbuger is incorrect.

[image]

The problem is that my gbd.exe is present in my cygwin/bin folder
and i have it also in my PATH (system variable)

[image]

What i've done so far:

delete, shutdown and reinstall cygwin from scratch.
Install Netbeans and try to run with cygwin config (and debugger) -> everthing is working and i can debug my program. I also try to select it manualy.

So the real question is why Clion think my gdb is not present?
An how can i make it work?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue unfortunately. Does it work if you remove the toolchain configured in CLion and create a new one?

Comment: No, Exactly the same problem

Comment: May I ask you to enable some logging and reproduce the problem once again? Open `Help | Debug Log Settings`; add `#com.jetbrains.cidr.cpp`; then open Toolchain settings to reproduce the "Not found" error. The collected logs can be found through `Help | Show Log in Explorer`. Please send the `idea.log` file with the link to this StackOverflow question through the https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new form, or to our issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP, whichever you find more convenient. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try to install GDB version 7.10.1

My settings:

[image: My settings]

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** check what versions of gcc, g++ and gdb you have installed. They should be of the same major version.

**Long answer:**
Try to launch gdb.exe from cygwin terminal. You will probably get something like this (I'm using mingw64 from msys2 so folder will be different):

```
$ gdb
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libgcc_s_seh-1.dll:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But you have gcc installed so you will have this DLL inside C:/msys64/mingw64/bin (in your case folder is different). The problem is that your gdb and gcc are of different major versions. I got this problem when installed mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-**7**.3.0-2 with mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb-**8**.2.1-1. That's why gdb was not able to launch and CLion was not able to check GDB version thus outputting "Not found" error.

If this is the case - remove gdb and install it again. Now with correct major version (same as gcc). Since you're using cygwin, launch cygwin setup again, search for gdb package (don't forget to change view to full) and change version to be the same as gcc. Or, alternatively, you can change gcc version to be the same as gdb (in my case this wasn't possible).